# Установка существующего в сети сайта на локальном хосте Denwer

Tags: html, denwer, localhost

Искал информацию, в основном речь идёт о том, как установить свой сайт.
Мне же нужно поработать с существующим сайтом. Как я понимаю, html сайта будет недостаточно? Что ещё нужно иметь и как это можно получить?

Comment: можно узнать что такое люди читают в 2017, что до сих пор устанавливают denwer?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский гуглил "запустить сайт на локальном хосте" - denwer выпал одним из первых) А что лучше использовать вместо него?

Comment: Если набор программ - то OpenServer. у него поддержка версий программ от старых до самых новых... а у того же Denwer php до сих пор 5.3 и заглох давно........... а в целом, конечно же, лучше настраивать всё ручками. Это долго, муторно, но при правильных настройках безопаснее

Comment: *php до сих пор 5.3* я его исторически пользую, стоит 5.6 и нет проблем сделать 7. И mysql свежий вполне

Comment: Сочувствую тем, кто сидит на легаси 5.3. И так ненавязчиво хочу напомнить, что через неделю-другую у [PHP 7.0  наступает end-of-life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не могу найти мануал по запуску существующего сайта, только по созданию нового. Для создания нового нужен движок, БД. Для моего случая они тоже ведь нужны? Откуда их брать? Движок, наверное, в некотором смысле универсален, а вот БД явно должна подходить для сайта. Её надо как-то получить?

Comment: @kosmo_tony для запуска сайта нужно минимум сервер (например apache или nginx) и сама страница html/php.  Всё. Сайт не обязан иметь БД или какой-то двиг или еще что-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так ведь apache и nginx входят в OpenServer

Comment: @kosmo_tony ну да.

Answer (score 2):

Я сейчас тестирую свой сайт с помощью Denwer. Советую вам прислушаться к комментариям и сразу смотреть в сторону OpenServer. 
Denwer - устаревшая прога, с ней будет много мороки. Например, будьте готовы к тому, что надо будет копаться в коде для того, чтобы поменять кодировку windows 1251 на utf-8. В противном случае будут иероглифы и больше 2х языков на сайте установить нельзя будет.